# Java configuration for Junit test of DAO class(Spring5+Hibernate5)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I try to test my DAO classes writed with Hibernate+Spring. I use Java configuration in my webapp and in tests, but now when I try to write tests i run into some troubles. How can I write configuration for Junit tests to make them work? 
my config file of main looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foxminded.university")
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(org.postgresql.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/University");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("qwerty123");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Audience.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Cathedra.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Faculty.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Group.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Lecture.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Subject.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Teacher.class);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        builder.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource);
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());      
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
    /.../
```

and my DAO which I want to test:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class HibernateAudienceDao implements AudienceDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateAudienceDao.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateAudienceDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Audience> findAll() {
        logger.debug("Find all audience");
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        List<Audience> audiences = session.createQuery("From Audience", Audience.class).list();

        return audiences;
    }
```

my config for test now is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foxminded.university")
public class TestsContextConfig {

    @Bean
    SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Audience.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Cathedra.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Faculty.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Group.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Lecture.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Subject.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Teacher.class);
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:University");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

and test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestsContextConfig.class })
@Transactional 
class HibernateAudienceDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    private AudienceDao audienceDao;

    @Test
    void whenFindAll_thenAllExistingAudiencesFound() {  
        List<Audience> expected = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("from Audience", Audience.class).list();
        List<Audience> actual = audienceDao.findAll();

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

and StackTrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in com.foxminded.university.dao.hibernate.TestsContextConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: Factory method 'transactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:198)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:202)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:382)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.<init>(HibernateTransactionManager.java:153)
    at com.foxminded.university.dao.hibernate.TestsContextConfig.transactionManager(TestsContextConfig.java:43)
    at com.foxminded.university.dao.hibernate.TestsContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f2bcc9d.CGLIB$transactionManager$1(<generated>)
    at com.foxminded.university.dao.hibernate.TestsContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f2bcc9d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4577d6b6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.foxminded.university.dao.hibernate.TestsContextConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f2bcc9d.transactionManager(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 84 more
```

I tried to make TestConfig looks like ContextConfig of main, but the Exception was rigth like that. How can I correctly config my tests without xml?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using Spring Data?

Comment: no, I just learn Spring and hibernate, may be I just miss something...

Comment: Your learning approach isn't _wrong_, but it's unnecessary. If you use Spring Boot and include Spring Data JPA, you just define an `interface AudienceRepository`, and your DAO gets created for you.

Comment: I need not to use Spring Boot yet, can I do it without using spring boot?

Comment: Why a special config for testing? Also you should use the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to provide easier configuration and better Spring and Hibernate integration. The fact that you have 2 different configs (one real and one for test) is already a sign you are doing things in the wrong way. Also your `DataSource` shouldn't be static, but rather a regular bean.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to do a unit test or integration test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I solved it. All couse of I not to create @Bean DataSource. In the end, I just @Import my main config file, which looks like in this link https://www.concretepage.com/questions/469
and just "override" bean DataSource (couse in app I use postgres, but in tests h2 db).
Now, all is OK